# Reply from the SIM800l module is being cut short

Tags: uart, sim800, raspberrypi-pico

I have a sim800l module connected to the Rpi pico hardware UART

```
/*
SIM800       RPi Pico
5v           *External 2A 5v supply*
GND          GND
VDD          3v3
TXD          GP1
RXD          GP0
*/

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  while (!Serial)
    ;

  Serial1.begin(9600);

  Serial.print("Initializing");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(".");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(".");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(".");

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);


  Serial1.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, it will back to OK
  updateSerial();
  delay(3000);

  Serial1.println("ATI"); //Returns the module name and revision.
  updateSerial();
  delay(3000);

  Serial1.println("AT+CCID"); //Read SIM information to confirm whether the SIM is plugged
  updateSerial();
  delay(3000);

  Serial1.println("AT+COPS?"); //Checks which network you are connected to
  updateSerial();
  delay(3000);

  Serial1.println("AT+COPS=?"); //Returns the list of operators present in the network.
  updateSerial();
  delay(3000);

}

void loop()
{
  updateSerial();
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(200);
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    Serial1.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while (Serial1.available())
  {
    Serial.write(Serial1.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }

}
```

terminal response

```
AT
OK
ATI
SIM800 R14.18

OK
AT+CCID
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"Vodaa TelAT+COPS=?
+COPS: (2,"Vodaa Telecom","Ver
```

From what i know so far the SIM800L always ends its response with an "OK" but there are some commands that are cut short and not end with OK.  such as AT+CDID and AT+COPS. I do not know if the problem is with the pico or with sim800l. The sim800l seems to be working fine so i suspect its with the pico but if so, it might be a problem with the internal libraries which is beyond me.  To supoort that theory the number of characters that is being cut is about 20 characters, so it might be a setting i have to adjust

Comment: hint:   `always ends its response with an "OK"` ... there is more than OK in the response ... count the number of characters that are actually received

Comment: the 115200 baud is slow. there are gaps between bytes so `while (Serial1.available())` can end before the complete response is read

Comment: @jsotola im sorry i dont get it.. I counted how many serial1.read() pe command.  AT=9 character, ATI = 27 , AT+CCID=31, AT+COPS? = 31,  AT+COPS=? is 9 followed by a long pause then responded with another 31.  looks like 31 is the limit,

Comment: @Juraj i dont think i can go any higher than that, i tried to explore that end thinking it was a baud rate issue, according to [this thread](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/sim800l-change-default-baud-rate) 115200 is the highest it can go

Comment: I didn't suggest higher baud rate but proper reading of the input

Answer (score 0):

Took me quite a while, but upon reading the pico's [documentation](https://arduino-pico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serial.html)

> The size of the receive FIFO may also be adjusted from the default 32
> bytes by using the setFIFOSize call prior to calling begin()
>
> ```
> Serial1.setFIFOSize(128); 
> Serial1.begin(baud);
> ```

settinng it to a much higher value like 256 solves the problem